error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'restricted_std'
It seems I can fix this by adding one by one of main.rs or lib.rs of ALL DEPENDENCIES with this magic line #![feature(restricted_std)].
For example, if the errors said:
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'restricted_std': You have attempted to use a standard library built for a platform that it doesn't know how to support. Consider building it for a known environment, disabling it with `#![no_std]` or overriding this warning by enabling this feature.
   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-core-0.3.30/src/stream.rs:218:32
    |
218 |     impl<S: Stream> Stream for std::panic::AssertUnwindSafe<S> {
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: add `#![feature(restricted_std)]` to the crate attributes to enable
    = note: this compiler was built on 2024-05-01; consider upgrading it if it is out of date

Then I need to insert #![feature(restricted_std)] at /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-core-0.3.30/src/lib.rs
It fixed for that lib, but there are 200 libs should I manually insert at the head of line of every single rust library.
From this build command:
cargo +nightly build -Z build-std=std,panic_abort -Z build-std-features=panic_immediate_abort --target=mipsel-unknown-none --release

Returning this errors:
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: add `#![feature(restricted_std)]` to the crate attributes to enable
    = note: this compiler was built on 2024-05-01; consider upgrading it if it is out of date

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'restricted_std': You have attempted to use a standard library built for a platform that it doesn't know how to support. Consider building it for a known environment, disabling it with `#![no_std]` or overriding this warning by enabling this feature.
   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/scopeguard-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:248:10
    |
248 |         !std::thread::panicking()
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: add `#![feature(restricted_std)]` to the crate attributes to enable
    = note: this compiler was built on 2024-05-01; consider upgrading it if it is out of date

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'restricted_std': You have attempted to use a standard library built for a platform that it doesn't know how to support. Consider building it for a known environment, disabling it with `#![no_std]` or overriding this warning by enabling this feature.
  --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-core-0.3.30/src/future.rs:98:42
   |
98 |     impl<F: FusedFuture> FusedFuture for std::panic::AssertUnwindSafe<F> {
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: add `#![feature(restricted_std)]` to the crate attributes to enable
   = note: this compiler was built on 2024-05-01; consider upgrading it if it is out of date

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'restricted_std': You have attempted to use a standard library built for a platform that it doesn't know how to support. Consider building it for a known environment, disabling it with `#![no_std]` or overriding this warning by enabling this feature.
   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-core-0.3.30/src/stream.rs:218:32
    |
218 |     impl<S: Stream> Stream for std::panic::AssertUnwindSafe<S> {
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: add `#![feature(restricted_std)]` to the crate attributes to enable
    = note: this compiler was built on 2024-05-01; consider upgrading it if it is out of date

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: could not compile `scopeguard` (lib) due to 9 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/getrandom-0.2.12/src/lib.rs:350:9
    |
350 |         imp::getrandom_inner(dest)?;
    |         ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `futures-core` (lib) due to 3 previous errors
error: could not compile `getrandom` (lib) due to 2 previous errors


Looks like you're working with a #![no_std] environment. Try to configure your dependencies the same (if possible). For example, if using the futures crate, make sure you disable default features.

@kmdreko Are you saying I must manually patch all 200 dependencies one by one?

No, you would just need to configure your direct dependencies (as long as they support no-std). For the futures example, put futures = { version = "...", default-features = false } as your dependency in Cargo.toml.

restricted_std is an internal feature. Do not use it.
If you are building for no_std, make sure all of your dependencies are no_std-compatible. There is no uniform way to do that, but usually a library will document if it supports no_std. Commonly, this is done with an enabled-by-default std feature, which means that you need to set default-features = false and possibly include the default features explicitly, if you need them. Note that some features may not be supported in no_std mode.
If you have a dependency that does not support no_std, you are out of luck. You may be able to patch the dependency to have a std feature (consider sending a PR!), but if std is fundamental to what this library does, you cannot use it. You will have to get rid of it.
